# When I nest two value event listeners, do they both run asynchronously or the the lower one waits for the higher one to be completed?

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an android application, using Firebase and Android Studio.
I had issues with retrieving values with value event listeners because i couldnt set values inside the `onDataChange` method to be used else where because it runs asynchronously, so the listener may or may not have completed its purpose before the value is needed outside. So I solved this issue by putting whatever needs to be done inside the `onDataChange` method(real life saver!).

But

the value i am retrieving in the `onDataChange` also happens to be needed inside another listener. like this

```
 DatabaseReference mLastnameReference = rootRef.child("users").child("12345678").child(phone);
        ValueEventListener lastnameListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                try {
                    yourid = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e){
                    //handle user not registered here

                }



DatabaseReference mBioReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(yourid).child("status");
                ValueEventListener bioListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Status = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                        mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
                        mTextField.setText(Status);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                };
                mBioReference.addValueEventListener(bioListener);
 }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mLastnameReference.addValueEventListener(lastnameListener);
```

the value im waiting for in the first listener is `yourid` . I also need that value to get a database reference to the node for the nested listener to be executed. But when i ran this code, both of them appear to be running at the same time. Hence, getting a null exception on the nested database reference, because the yourid appears to not have been retrieved at that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you shared, the value of `users/12345678/$phone` will be read before you attach the nested listener. But the value might be null, which you code doesn't handle correctly:

```
DatabaseReference mLastnameReference = rootRef.child("users").child("12345678").child(phone);
ValueEventListener lastnameListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String id = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
        if (id != null) {
            DatabaseReference mBioReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(id).child("status");
            ValueEventListener bioListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Status = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    mTextField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
                    mTextField.setText(Status);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
            };
            mBioReference.addValueEventListener(bioListener);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
};
mLastnameReference.addValueEventListener(lastnameListener);
```

I've replaced the `try`-`catch` with a regular `if` and made `id` a local variable, which removes the chance that some other part of your code sets it to `null`. It also throw exceptions in `onCancelled` now, since it's best to not ignore those authorization problems.